# SublimeText build system for C/C++ in Terminal.

Tags: linux, sublimetext3, gnome-terminal

I am using "Linux Centos-7" and here I install "SublimeText-3".
C/C++ codes are running well in SublimeText Console but I want to run those code in Linux terminal. 
I include a couple line in SublimeText build system like--

```
{
"shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe\"",
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++, source.cpp",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
    }
]}
```

Above code is only create a executable file. which I have to run manually in terminal.

And,

```
{
"cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++, source.cxx, source.cpp",
"variants":
[
    {
        "cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
        "variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "shell": true,
        "cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"${file_path}/${file_base_name};echo;echo;  echo Press ENTER to continue; read line;exit; exec bash\"'"]
    }
]  
    }

]    }
```

This code can run only existing file in terminal.

Now, I just want to write code in SublimeText and execute it in terminal automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in the same situation some days ago after I installed Sublime. I researched for a bit and ended up with this.

```
{
  "cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++0x", "$file", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
  "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
  "working_dir": "${file_path}",
  "selector": "source.c, source.c++, source.cxx, source.cpp",
  "variants": 
  [ 
    {
      "name": "Run",
      "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ -std=c++0x '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' &&  xterm -e bash -c '${file_path}/${file_base_name}; read'"]  
    }
  ]    
}
```

You probably have to install xterm too.